# How to create a service on the bridge network and the host network?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've got a docker-compose.yml file with two services, web and auth.

Web will redirect to auth when authentication is necessary. Secondly, web talks to auth directly.

So it makes sense that my host machine is able to access both services and this works great since I can forward the ports, 3000 and 9000 for my host network.

However, the issue is that I cannot use the same localhost:9000 route when the apps talk directly to each other since that is on a separate bridge network.

Can I not have the auth service on both the host and bridge network? I've tried `docker network connect container host` and that explicitly fails. How do I get the two apps talking to each other while still being able to access them externally?

Comment: Can you paste your compose file? Why do you need any of the containers to run on the host network?

Answer (score 0):

Each container has its own localhost which is not the same of the machine running them.

You could link the containers either specifying both the service name and a link alias (SERVICE:ALIAS), or just the service name. eg:

```
web: 
  ...
  links:
   - auth
   - auth:ldap

auth:
  ...
  links:
  - web
```

> Containers for the linked service will be reachable at a hostname identical to the alias, or the service name if no alias was specified.
>
> Links also express dependency between services in the same way as depends_on, so they determine the order of service startup.

(cit. [docker-compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/links))